# Send value with submit link in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, hyperlink, submit

I want to send a value with a link in a submit form. The form method is post and I like to keep it that way, otherwise my problem would have been pretty easy using something like "?myvale=1".

So this code illustrates what I wan't:

```
<a href="#" name="submit value="1" onclick="document.editDelete.submit()" class="button icon edit">Test</a>
```

How can I accomplish what I want with javascript or something like that?

Comment: The `name` attribute of your markup seems to be incorrect. It seems to be missing the closing double-quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not set a hidden form value in a submit handler?

```
<form ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="theParam"/>
  ...

<a href="#" ... onclick="handler()">Test</a>

function handler() {
  document.editDelete.theParam.value = "the value";
  document.editDelete.submit();
}
```

(Adjust names/etc. to match your HTML.)

Comment: Thanks for answer, all. Can't get it to work properly, nothing is getting printed out when outputing the $_POST

My code looks like this:
`....
<head>
........ 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function handler() {
     document.editDelete.theParam.value = "the value";
     document.editDelete.edit();
  }
 </script
</head>
......
<form .. name="editDelete" ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="theParam"/>
  ...
  <a href="#" name="edit" onclick="document.editDelete.submit(); handler();" class="button icon edit">Test</a>
</form>
.....`

Comment: @Fredrik Here you do at least two things wrong: you submit before you call the handler, and you call `document.editDelete.edit()`, which won't do anything at all. The *handler* does the submit, and I have no idea what `edit()` is.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Thanks for the help, now I got everything right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden form field and set its value in your `onclick` handler, just before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hidden input and `onsubmit` set the input value to whatever you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Hidden form value would do it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="your_input" value="1"/>
```

Then just submit your form as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

at the form tag the action attribute attribute="/page?myvale=1" and keep the the method get .you will receive a get query string + the posted data